# Summing up arrays without doubles

Tags: python, arrays, function, sum, double

I would like to know if I have generated the 3 arrays in the manner below, how can I sum all the numbers up from all 3 arrys without summing up the ones that appear in each array.

(I would like to only som upt 10 once but I cant add array X_1 andX_2 because they both have 10 and 20, I only want to som up those numbers once.)

Maybe this can be done by creating a new array out of the X_1, X_2 and X_3 what leave out doubles?

```
 def get_divisible_by_n(arr, n):
    return arr[arr%n == 0]
x = np.arange(1,21)

X_1=get_divisible_by_n(x, 2)
#we get array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])

X_2=get_divisible_by_n(x, 5)
#we get array([ 5, 10, 15, 20])
    
X_3=get_divisible_by_n(x, 3)
#we get array([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18])
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do, and why?

Comment: actually i wanted to add all numbers between 1 and 20 that can be divide by 2, 3 and 5. I already figured out how to identify to which numbers this applies, but from here I don't know how to som them all up and avoid suming up numbers that appear several times as they can be divided by 2 and 3 or by 2 and 5

Comment: In that case, perhaps it is better to change your "filter" so that you get all the values you need in one go? Try if the numbers are divisible by 2 or divisible by 3 or divisible by 5 and keep them if any of the requirements are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is me again!
here is my solution using numpy, cuz i had more time this time:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1,21)

divisable_by = lambda x: arr[np.where(arr % x == 0)]
n_2 = divisable_by(2)
n_3 = divisable_by(3)
n_5 = divisable_by(5)
what_u_want = np.unique( np.concatenate((n_2, n_3, n_5)) )
# [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really efficient and not using numpy but here is one solution:

```
def get_divisible_by_n(arr, n):
    return [i for i in arr if i % n == 0]
   

x = [i for i in range(21)]

X_1 = get_divisible_by_n(x, 2)
X_2 = get_divisible_by_n(x, 5)
X_3 = get_divisible_by_n(x, 3)
X_all = X_1+X_2+X_3
y = set(X_all)
print(sum(y)) # 142
```

Comment: Hope I helped ad if so please write the comment that it did

Comment: I get an error for X_all. ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (4,) ```  how can I fix this?

Comment: it works if i do it exactly as you wrote, but why does it not work with how I defined x?

Comment: Please note that there is a `set`-like operator included in `numpy`, namely `numpy.unique` it is probably more efficient to use that, rather than the set operator. Not that it matters for problems of the size in this question, but...

Comment: for which size should I switch to numpy.unique? I actually plan to use a range of 1000 but I used here 21 just to see which codes would work